# Burn a DVD to play video on standalone player and include autorun program for PC

Tags: dvd, burning, layout, autorun, authoring

Can you burn a DVD film that will play on a standard DVD player but also include on the disk some pc readable files that would auto launch on a PC?

I want to create a dvd disk that essentailly has 2 purposes:

1. When a DVD is inserted into a standard DVD player it plays like a normal DVD film, i.e. you get the DVD menu and you can play the movie
2. When you insert the dvd into a pc it auto launches an exe file and behaves like a normal data disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to burn it initially as DVD-Video, not DVD-ROM, in order to have the correct block sizes and file-system (UDF 1.02, IIRC) for it to play on a normal DVD player. This means that you must burn first the DVD using a video-creation product, before adding the data.

You may afterward add the data files, as the DVD player will normally just ignore files that it doesn't recognize. When you burn the DVD, the video burner software must be able to burn a non-finalized DVD.

Comment: If an auto run was included on the dvd-rom side would the PC auto launch that instead of the DVD content? Or would the user have to quit dvd-video playback and launch the dvd-rom content manually?

Comment: @ArchieVersace: I'm not sure, and the action might vary between versions of Windows. If I had to guess, I would say that autoplay would occur, rather than autorun, as the DVD is identified as formatted with a video-typed file-system and block-size.

Comment: it's not necessary to burn the video stuff first, as long as you *burn it as DVD-Video*.  the utilities used *should* correctly handle moving the non-video files to the end of the disc.

Comment: Agreed, if your burner can burn data in DVD-Video. However, not every burner supports burning data in DVD-Video.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines with Nero. I think it's called dual-useage disk. I'm not sure of any alternatives.